# Get Exact child of their parent element. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I was having a hard time to call a certain element. 
What I was supposed to do is get the

`li.parent.iced-tea span a` element. But the problem is it also **affects** the **LEVEL2** li span a tag.

```
<li class="level1-parent has-children level1 parent iced-tea open">

      <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="/tea/iced-tea/iced-gold"><span>iced tea</span></a></span>

    <ul>
      <li class="first level2-active level2 active iced-ceylon-gold">
        <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="/tea/iced-tea/iced-silver"><span>iced ceylon silver</span></a></span>

      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So I was wondering, how to get the exact child without going to other element.

Here's the code that I'm calling.

```
$("#vertnav ul li.iced-tea span a")
```

Any solution for this stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`):

```
$("#vertnav ul li.iced-tea > span a")
```

In other words, only select span links that are direct children of `li.iced-tea` elements.